# Checking if the status changes using while loop

Tags: python, api, while-loop

New to programming. I am creating a script where I post an API search and get the status of the progress. The status can be "COMPLETED", "EXECUTE", "WAITING". I am struggling with how to keep checking the status. Below is my attempt to do this:

```
for searches in search
 ............ # for loop to perform another task
 def check_status():
            check_search = requests.get("https:example.com/search") #Getting the search status
            check_results = check_search.json() 
            check_results_str = json.dumps(check_results, indent=2)
            searchresp = json.loads(check_results_str)
            search_status = searchresp['status'] # Extracting the Status key from the JSON response
            print(search_status)


            while search_status != "COMPLETED": # Checking if the search status is completed
                print ("Search Not yet completed,searching again..") 
                sleep(3)
                check_status() # Attempting to call check_status function again to get the status
```

The script is working as far as getting the Search status, when it reaches the while loop, the for loop breaks and scripts finishes. I have also tried to indent the check_status() to line up with while loop. This way the program executes however the script never runs a get API search again to get the search status. 
I am looking to call the check_status function again until the search_status is "COMPLETED". 
Any ideas how I can achieve this? Thanks

Comment: It's probably a case of an infinite recursion.

Comment: I believe you should return the status of the requests.get to the calling program, and then make a call to check_status again.  When you call the function from itself, it can sometimes crash and what you are doing is recursion. You are also assuming the API will return 'Completed' at some point in time, which it may not.

Comment: @Rupin Thanks. So I return the search_status for the check_status function. And how do I go about calling the function again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to the SO community.

You should limit the number of retries to know if the API returned a COMPLETED Status

```
def check_status():
    check_search = requests.get("https:example.com/search") #Getting the search status
    check_results = check_search.json() 
    check_results_str = json.dumps(check_results, indent=2)
    searchresp = json.loads(check_results_str)
    search_status = searchresp['status'] # Extracting the Status key from the JSON response
    print(search_status)


    if search_status != "COMPLETED": # Checking if the search status is completed
        return False
    else:
        return True


RETRIES=100

for i in range (0,RETRIES):
    APIStatus=check_status()
    if(APIStatus):
        break
```

You could then keep a log of which requests failed, so you can attempt to understand why they failed or for future audit logging.

The Retries value I have chosen is arbitrary, it can also be dependent on how fast (time based) you expect your answer to be come back.

Comment: Thank you so much Rupin, this is working like charm. I understand the most part of what we did here, however when define "if(APIStatus): break" - what is this specifically doing, I assume this will break the for loop as soon as the status is COMPLETED.

Comment: That is correct. You could determine what to do when the APIstatus is true, maybe save the data etc. The break is there because it is possible your answer could come back in less than 100 retries, so we break out of the loop, and start processing the next request.

Comment: Thanks Rupin, that's exactly what I am doing. After the status is COMPLETED, I have other functions which will then get the search and save it! Thanks again.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered, by clicking the tick mark next to the answer.

Comment: Marked as answer. Thanks